# Is there a way to get HTTP request parameter using wildcard?

Tags: java, httprequest

We have a service that get values from formData in http requests.

Some parameters are `packaging1_1` or `packaging1_2` or `packaging1_3` etc

We are using the following code to get the parameter value from `HttpServletRequest request`

```
String doseForm = request.getParameter("packaging1_0");
```

Is there any way to use the code with wildcard in the last number? e.g.

```
String doseForm = request.getParameter("packaging1_WILDCARD");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only get all the names and compare them on your own, like so:

```
Set<String> packaging1Params = new TreeSet<>();
for(Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames(); names.hasMoreElements();) {
  String name = names.nextElement();
  if(name.startsWith("packaging1")) {
    packaging1Params.add(name);
  }
}
```

And then get the values for all the filtered names.